# Poisson bracket of Hamiltonian with Hamiltonian always vanishes

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian, time-evolution, poisson-brackets

Since Poisson bracket of Hamiltonian with Hamiltonian always vanishes then in case of explicit time dependence of Hamiltonian, how does Poisson bracket gives correct result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There still remains the *partial derivative in time*. We have in fact that the time evolution of a function on a symplectic manifold is given by

$$\frac{df}{dt} = \{f, H\}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} $$

For the Hamiltonian, if does not depend explicitly on time we get

$$ \frac{dH}{dt} = \{H,H\}+\frac{\partial H}{\partial t} = 0 $$

which is what we want since it has to be a conserved quantity. If the Hamiltonian depends on time in an explicit way, we obtain

$$ \frac{dH}{dt} = \{H, H\} + \frac{\partial H}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial t} $$

so the variation in time of the hamiltonian is governed by the sole part which explicitly depends on time such as a dissipative quantity.